# C# compression and JavaScript decompression

Tags: c#, javascript, compression

I've got some strings that I need to compress server-side in C#, then decompress client-side in JavaScript. What can I use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you're fetching this data over HTTP, is there any reason you can't do this at the HTTP level? (See [this article for information about HTTP compression](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/compress/).)

That way you shouldn't need to do anything on the client side, apart from making sure that the request includes the appropriate `Accept-Encoding` header. Depending on your server, you may be able to just tweak some server settings to get the compression automatically on that side too...

To be honest, it's worth breaking out [WireShark](http://wireshark.org) to check exactly what's going up and down the wire already. It's just possible you've already got compression without knowing it :)

Comment: Just check the headers with something like Firebug. The server response is cleary marked as gzipped if it is, and it has no Content-Lenght because of that (on the fly compression). Firebug will show you the actual bytes transferred.

Comment: Could also use Fiddler [http://www.fiddler2.com] instead of WireShark.
Imho, it is easier to use, if you need HTTP-level data only and can make your connection go through a proxy.